# Mean of the summations of group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I have a data that looks like this:

```
    A     B     C
    1     1     1
    1     1     5
    1     2     7
    1     2     3
    2     1     8
    2     1    10
    2     2     1
    2     2     4
```

I need to group by A and B and sum C then get the mean of (sum C) for each unique value in A

Output1:

```
A   B   SumC
1   1   6
    2   10
2   1   18
    2   5
```

Output2:

```
A   Mean C
1   8
2   11.5
```

My attempt:
DailyCount_ps = (df_new.groupby(["A","B"])["C"].sum()).rename(“Sum C”)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do it in 2 steps:

```
df = df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False)['C'].sum().rename({'C': 'Sum C'}, axis=1)
df['Mean C'] = df.groupby('A')['Sum C'].transform('mean')

df

   A  B  Sum C  Mean C
0  1  1      6     8.0
1  1  2     10     8.0
2  2  1     18    11.5
3  2  2      5    11.5
```